# How can I enable the touch-pad in 11.10 while I disabled it using touchpad-indicator in 11.04?

Tags: 11.10, touchpad

I used touchpad-indicator to disable the touch-pad in Ubuntu 11.04.

Now I update to Ubuntu 11.10, and I installed touchpad-indicator in ubuntu 11.10 again but I can not enable the touch-pad.

When I press the shortcut set in ubuntu 11.04, it says "Error while trying to run `(/usr/share/touchpad-indicator/change_touchpad_state.py)`" , and I search in that dir and find out there's no that file(change_touchpad_state.py).

I'm thinking maybe this is because the new version touchpad-indicator(0.9) works in a different way.

So how can I enable my touch-pad without installing ubuntu 11.04 and enable it on and then switch to 11.10 again ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and have managed to correct the error message but still do not have touchpad indicator working properly.

I found that after my update to 11.10 the shortcut I had in 11.04 was still there but pointing to the wrong directory.

I went to System settings >Keyboard >Shortcuts and cleared my shortcut which was under Custom.  This fixed the error message, but the shortcut feature in Touchpad-Indicator does not work.